# Long list of bib-files in texmaker

Tags: bibtex, texmaker

I have got a long list of bib-files

```
\bibliographystyle{siam}
\bibliography{../mybib/bibA,../mybib/bibB,../mybib/bibC, and so on }
```

My problem is two-fold:

(i) First, it seems that the argument of \bibliography must not contain linebreaks, so I really have to write a huge list of bibfiles in one single line. This does not make the code more readable, so is there a way work around this?

(ii) Second, I use Texmaker 3.2 on my system. However, it seems the editor component of Texmaker doesn't let me edit my code beyond a certain column position, although it still shows my code. I regard this as very annoying and I would like to know whether this can be corrected somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In relation to problem i)

The following works for me in TexStudio

```
\bibliography{fileA,%
              fileB,%
              fileC}
```

The `%` at the end of each line fixes the problem which you describe.

Not sure about problem ii)

Comment: Strange enough for me, this seems to solve the first problem. Is there any logical reason why this works?

Comment: When LaTeX encounters a % character while processing an input file, it ignores the rest of the current line, the line break, and all whitespace at the beginning of the next line.
This can be used to write notes into the input file, which will not show up in the printed version.